# Set mvim as visual editor from crontab AND git commit

Tags: bash, unix, editor

How do I set up MacVim as the visual editor for git commit messages (no forking) and still have it work with crontab editing (no parameters?) without having to manually type "mvim /path/to/crontabfile"?

My current VISUAL editor is set to "mvim -f" in my .bashrc, which works to get MacVim for git commit messages.
When setting up a new crontab (crontab -e) I got the following message:

```
crontab: no crontab for USER - using an empty one
crontab: mvim -f: No such file or directory
crontab: "mvim -f" exited with status 1

crontab: mvim -f: No such file or directory
```

Comment: temporarily doing this: env VISUAL=vim crontab -e for console vim mode

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the particular `crontab` executable you're having is not running the editor via the shell but directly using `exec*()` or a similar call. That means it doesn't handle passing arguments to it.

In order to check that, please try something like `VISUAL=mvim` -- if it works that way, then this is the issue. You can create a wrapper script like `/usr/local/bin/myvim` which would look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec mvim -f "${@}"
```

And use `VISUAL=myvim` (this may need to be the full path, depending on your `PATH` setting) then.

Comment: did not work, btw mvim is already a wrapper to MacVim.app. It's source can be found here: https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/blob/master/src/MacVim/mvim -- of note, it does this: exec "$VIM_APP_DIR/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim" -g $opts ${1:+"$@"}